# two processes accessing shared memory without lock

Tags: c, process, operating-system

There are two variables in a shared memory (shared by two processes), one is a general `int` variable (call it **intVar**) with initial value say *5* and the other variable of `pid_t` type (call it **pidVar**) with initial value 0.

Now the code  to be developed is that both the processes try to add a number (which is fixed and different for both these processes) to the `intVar` variable in the shared memory (there is no lock on memory ever) and if a process finds the `pidVar` variable in the shared memory to be having the value *0*, only then it will update it with it's own `pid`.

So the point of confusion for me is:

1: Since both the processes are trying to add a number, then ultimately the final value in the `intVar` variable will be same all the time after both the processes are done adding a number?

2: The `pidVar` in the shared memory  is going to be totally random? Right?

Comment: No locking? Are you supposed to use atomic operations instead?

Comment: @Shawn That is the requirement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Not necessarily.   Adding to intVar involves reading from memory, calculating a new value then writing back to memory.  The two processes could read at the *same* time, which would mean two writes, so whichever came last would win.
2. pidVar is defined to be initially zero.   Either or both of the processes may find it that way, causing either or both to update it.   So you will get one of them.

Your assignment says no *locking*, which is a loaded and imprecise term.  Locking can refer to physical layer operations such as bus protocols right through high level operations such as inter process communication.   I prefer synchronizing is locking; thus everything from a bus protocol to message passing is locking.

Some processors create the illusion of atomic memory, for example by having opcodes like "lock: addl $2, (%sp)"; but in reality that is a form of *synchronization* implemented in the processor via *busy wait*. Synchronization is locking; thus that would be in violation of your assignment.

Some processors slice the memory protocol down so you can control interference.  Typical implementations use a *load linked, store conditional* pattern, where the store fails if anything has interfered with cache line identified by the load linked instruction.  This permits composing atomics by retry operations; but is again synchronization, thus locking.

Comment: Or reads and/or writes to the memory might not even be atomic, so the result could be utter nonsense.